# Entity relationship - DB Design

Tags: database, entity, specialization

I am trying to think of the best design for trainers and clients database.

My initial thought was this:

1. Entity `person` with common attributes of clients and trainers (name, dob, etc.). A client can have only one trainer. One trainer can have many clients.
2. I wonder whether creating an entity `user` for controlling clients and trainers privileges, or just adding an attribute `Role` in `person`

Another thing I had considered was having everything in a single entity with a recursive relationship?

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, this is what I came up with:

User(UserID, Name, Dob, Username, Password, will keep address here too...)
UserRole(UserId, RoleId)
Role(RoleId, Role)
RolePermission(RoleId, PermissionId)
Permission(PermissionId, Permission)
Client(ClientId, UserId, NextOfKin, ...)
Trainer(TrainerId, UserId, Level, ...)
ClientTrainer(ClientId, TrainerId)

Before I continue, I'd like to hear your opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trainers and Clients from an entity perspective probably have different data that you care to track about each one.  You can still have a global users table, but the trainer and client should have a 1:1 relationship with the user entity.  You can then have a join table between clients and trainers.  I would suggest a many to many relationship here, just in case someone really wants to get in shape and wants to have 2 trainers.

Comment: Would that map a global table, let's say 'user' and a second table with the attributes of clients and trainers and their role? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how specific you want to be.  If the data you want to track differs greatly beyond the core user data then I would recommend two different tables.  Even if someone happens to be both a trainer and a client, you still don't have redundancy as the trainer entity should have trainer specific data, whereas the client is client specific data, with any global data being represented in your user table.

Comment: Thank you Nick. I went for two different tables allowing to add more specific data in future if necessary. And I will use the join table between Client and Trainer to keep the date when a client has started training with a new trainer.

Answer (score 0):

Can trainers have trainers?  For example, a trainer who specializes in triathletes might be a weak swimmer and have a swim coach.

I like the `Role` design myself.

Comment: Yes, trainers can have a trainer, which could be himself or another, allowing a trainer to create an exercise programme for himself or to other trainers. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Then you definitely need a Person-Role design that's a hierarchy.